# convert cable modem config file to json/xml/java objects

Tags: java, json, xml, configuration-files, data-conversion

Please help me.
I am working n/w domain project.
I have config file like this.

```
Main
{
    NetworkAccess 1;
    MaxCPE 3;
    GlobalPrivacyEnable 1;
    BaselinePrivacy
    {
        AuthTimeout 10;
        ReAuthTimeout 10;
        AuthGraceTime 600;
        OperTimeout 10;
        ReKeyTimeout 10;
        TEKGraceTime 600;
        AuthRejectTimeout 60;
        SAMapWaitTimeout 1;
        SAMapMaxRetries 4;
    }
    UsServiceFlow
    {
        UsServiceFlowRef 1;
        QosParamSetType 7;
        ServiceClassName "USFLOW_NAME";
    }
    DsServiceFlow
    {
        DsServiceFlowRef 101;
        QosParamSetType 7;
        ServiceClassName "DSFLOW_NAME";
    }
}
```

I need to convert it into any format like json/xml/java objects.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read the [guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/2225619)

Comment: If you want to convert just one file, you can try it by hand. You can use https://jsoneditoronline.org/#/ to make a JSON file.